# Popular Python type checkers give a false negative with Any annotation

Tags: python, types, static-analysis

I tested the following snippet with 4 common type checkers for Python and, to my surprise, none of them complained:

```py
from typing import Any

def length(s: str) -> int:
    return len(s)

def any_length(o: Any) -> int:
    return length(o)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(any_length(1234))
```

It's easy to predict that running this code will result in an exception:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

**mypy**:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

**pytype**:

```
Success: no errors found
```

**pyright**:

```
0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
Completed in 0.435sec
```

**pyre**:

```
ƛ No type errors found
```

I would expect at least a warning saying that `Any` is not a subtype of `str` and therefore application of `length: str -> int` to an object of type `Any` is unsafe. Is there something about these particular types that makes it difficult for type checkers to consider this simple case? The problem of determining whether a concrete type is a subtype of another doesn't seem undecidable, but maybe I'm wrong here?

Comment: But `Any` *is* a subtype of `str`; that's the beauty and purpose of `Any`.

Comment: Related: [typing.Any vs object?](/q/39817081/4518341)

Answer (score 6):

`Any` is not just a synonym for `object`.

`Any` is somewhat like both a supertype of any type, *and* a subtype of any type, whereas `object` is a supertype of all types but only a subtype of itself. (Which is not to say that `Any` *is* a sub- or supertype of any type, since `Any` is not a type.)

Intuitively,

1. If a function expects a value of type `Any`, it will accept anything, as if `Any` were a universal supertype.
2. But no matter what a function expects, it will accept a value of type `Any`, as if `Any` were a universal subtype.

A fuller description of `Any` can be found in the [Summary of gradual typing](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing) in PEP 484, "The Theory of Type Hints". But the `Any` type is basically what allows you to type-check code that doesn't provide hints for everything. If something has no type hint, it is assumed to have type `Any`, which means there are no static restrictions on how it is used, just as you would expect from a dynamially typed language.

---

Specifically, as the static type of `o` is `Any`, it is a valid argument for the function `length` which expects a `str` (as `Any` is consistent with `str`). That doesn't mean `any_length(1234)` will work at runtime, because you basically lied about the type of value `any_length` requires to pass to `length`.

Comment: To put a finer point on it, if you want type checking and you want to support _any_ type (that is actually a type), use `object`, not `Any`. Theoretically, not `def any_length(o: Any) -> int: ...`, but `def any_length(o: object) -> int: ...`. (Practically, though, `def any_length(o: Sized) -> int:` is probably better.)

Comment: Thank you for the PEP link. But I still find it difficult to grasp the (subtle, I imagine), distinction here: `A type t1 is consistent with a type t2 if t1 is a subtype of t2. (But not the other way around.)` but at the same time `Any is consistent with every type. (But Any is not a subtype of every type.)` and `Every type is consistent with Any. (But every type is not a subtype of Any.)`

Comment: I should take that wording out of my answer, since `Any` is not a type itself, only an "extension" of the class of types that allows for the definition of the `is-consistent-with` relation.

Comment: real and true i agree